# How do I make table links in between 2 Access databases persist?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have 2 Access 2013 databases, A and B. A is used as a front-end with links to tables in B. A is used by multiple users. Sometimes when opening, the links need to be refeshed using "Linked Table Manager." Sometimes the "Linked Table Manager" will show the linked tables being in an upper level folder, which is not the case. Is there something I can do to have A always open without the need of refreshing/resetting the links? Could multiple users be an issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely that not all users access the two database files using the same network path. The only reason I can think of that the links would not persist is if the front end is opened in a way that the path to the back end does not exist or is inaccessible.

If you are using mapped drives make sure all relevant drive mappings for all users are the same, or even better create your links using absolute UNC paths.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that the drive/folder on which the backend (base B) is stored is mapped the same way on all clients.
Or link the tables using UNC (`\\myServer\someShare\folder\filename.mdb`) instead of mapped drive (`s:\somefolder\filename.mdb`).